# How to add a figure to only a particular group in vb.net RDLC report

Tags: vb.net, rdlc

I have an RDLC report which sums totals for each group in VB.Net. It is working fine but what I want to do is to add a figure outside the group to only a particular group based on users selection.

Assuming there are three groups: Food Dept, Security Dept and Sales Dept. I want a figure 2000 to be added to only the Food Dept without affecting the Sales and Security Dept. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an expression like this:

```
=Sum(Fields!ValueToSum.Value) + IIf(Fields!Departments.Value = "Food Dept", 2000, 0)
```

This is a simple example: use `ReportParameters` instead of constant (`"Food Dept"`, `2000`).

Answer (score 0):

I would add a parameter and assign the value. An integer parameter for ex: `@FoodDeptOffset` can be added to the fields as

`=Sum(Fields!FoodDept.Value) + (Parameters!FoodDeptOffset.Value)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks A lot for the answers. I was able to sort it out by passing a parameter which did the trick. On the main form which loads the Reportviewer I attached A combo box giving the users an option to select which field the wanted to add to and the passed it as a parameter to the rdlc report.